# Active on Scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, html, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to highlight a different list item on scroll but I can't get it to work now that I ported it over to this wordpress installation..

Here's my current menu:

```
<div id="navigation">
    <ul>
        <li class="nav1">
            <a href="#post-31"></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav2">
            <a href="#post-28"></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav3">
            <a href="#post-17"></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav4">
            <a href="#post-12"></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav5">
            <a href="#post-5"></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav6">
            <a href="#post-1"></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And Here is the Javascript:

```
//#### Change Active Menu Item 
// Cache selectors
var lastId,
    topMenu = $("#navigation ul"),
    topMenuHeight = topMenu.outerHeight()+15,
    // All list items
    menuItems = topMenu.find("a"),
    // Anchors corresponding to menu items
    scrollItems = menuItems.map(function(){
      var item = $($(this).attr("href"));
      if (item.length) { return item; }
    });

// Bind click handler to menu items
// so we can get a fancy scroll animation
menuItems.click(function(e){
  var href = $(this).attr("href"),
      offsetTop = href === "#" ? 0 : $(href).offset().top-topMenuHeight+1;
  //$('html, body').stop().animate({ scrollTop: offsetTop }, 300);
  e.preventDefault();
});

// Bind to scroll
$(window).scroll(function(){
   // Get container scroll position
   var fromTop = $(this).scrollTop()+topMenuHeight;

   // Get id of current scroll item
   var cur = scrollItems.map(function(){
     if ($(this).offset().top < fromTop)
       return this;
   });
   // Get the id of the current element
   cur = cur[cur.length-1];
   var id = cur && cur.length ? cur[0].id : "";

   if (lastId !== id) {
       lastId = id;
       // Set/remove active class
       menuItems
         .parent().removeClass("active")
         .end().filter("[href=#"+id+"]").parent().addClass("active");
   }                   
});
```

I can tell the script is kind of working since when scrolling it puts the active class on the #post-1 list item, but it does not move from there.

Can anything be seen in the code that is incorrect?

Comment: any chance you can thor this into a jsfiddle so I can have a play around

Comment: @Alex Probably not, the issue I'm having is it worked fine on the static site but when I added it to the wordpress theme thats where the problem started.. I converted all "$" to "jQuery" in the custom JS file but still not working properly.. is there any way to check if the javascript is conflicting with anything in wordpress?

Comment: @JoeBobby, one good way would be if indeed you could post it on jsfiddle. Start with the REAL htm output, then add your js. If it works then the problem might be some collision. If it doesn't then the problem is in your js, and has nothing to do with the rest of WP. Was the static html code 100% identical to WP's output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for some reason, adding 'order' => 'ASC' to the menu seemed to get it to work.  I don't know why, but its working now